# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bind' error in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having 'fun' with Python TkInter. Unfortunately, my code returns an error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bind'

I've already assigned `StringVar` type to my variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar
from typing import Type

window = tkinter.Tk()

label = tkinter.Label(
    text='Hello TkInter',
    foreground='white',
    background='black',
)
entry = tkinter.Entry(
    foreground='yellow',
    background='blue',
    width=50,
)


UserEntry: Type[StringVar] = entry.get()


def PrintUserEntry():
    print(UserEntry.widget.get())


label.pack()
entry.pack()
UserEntry.bind('<Enter>', PrintUserEntry())
window.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You defined `UserEntry` as the result of `entry.get()` therefore it will be a string not a tkinter widget. Change `UserEntry.bind('<Enter>', PrintUserEntry())` to `entry.bind('<Enter>', PrintUserEntry)`

Comment: Btw you know that the event `<Enter>` is for when the user's mouse hovers over the widget. I think you wanted to use `<Return>` which is the enter key on the keyboard.

Comment: Also just noticed it but you need to change `def PrintUserEntry()` to `def PrintUserEntry(event)` because when you bind an event is passed in the function.

Comment: Now it returns 2 errors. Code launches and I can enter text, but when i press enter this comes up:

`line 1884, in __call__ return self.func(*args)`
and
`line 22, in PrintUserEntry 
print (UserEntry.widget.get())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'widget'`

Comment: That is because `UserEntry` is still a string not a `StringVar`. Look at my answer bellow.

Comment: To use `StringVar` you first have to create it. It isn't automatically created for each `Entry`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Krzysztoff, Please edit your question with the updates you made, and include an extra code block with the current error output.

Answer (score 1):

The full working code:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar
from typing import Type

window = tkinter.Tk()

label = tkinter.Label(
    text='Hello TkInter',
    foreground='white',
    background='black',
)
entry = tkinter.Entry(
    foreground='yellow',
    background='blue',
    width=50,
)


UserEntry: Type[str] = entry.get()


def PrintUserEntry(event):
    print(entry.get())


label.pack()
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<Return>', PrintUserEntry)
window.mainloop()
```

First of all when you wrote `UserEntry.bind('<Enter>', PrintUserEntry())`, you didn't want to automatically call the function so you where actually trying to do this: `UserEntry.bind('<Enter>', PrintUserEntry)`.

Second of all when you defined `UserEntry` it was actually a `str` not a `StringVar` so both `UserEntry.widget.get()` and `UserEntry.bind(...)` would fail.

Also you need to change `def PrintUserEntry()` to `def PrintUserEntry(event)` because when you bind, an event is passed in the function.

Lastly, when bind to `<Enter>` it is actually for when the user's mouse hovers over the widget. I think you wanted to use `<Return>` which is the enter key on the keyboard.

Comment: @Krzysztoff: See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)